# Resizing a DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that has a DataGridView as it's main component. I need to resize the DGV when the user maximizes the form.

As I read online, this cannot be done programatically.

The program is written in C# and uses WinForms.  How would you do it?

Comment: "As I read online, this cannot be done programatically. How would you do it" First you say you cant do it then you ask how can we do it..Let me see, pull really hard to expand it.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: JonH, sure thing, will try it. Sigh.

SLaks, WinForm, but Mitja Bonca answered it perfectly, thanks!

Comment: EtherDragon, will do but it seems I need to wait a couple of minutes until I can mark it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Anshor property, and set to all four sides (top, right, botton and left).
This way the datagridview will resize together with form.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the docking property,